# C#. Calling async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I have async method:

```
public static async Task<HashSet<string>> getLinks(string page)
    {
        // GET request
        string str = await Client.get(page);

        // Pattern for http address
        Regex regx = new Regex(@"((http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        str = str.Replace("&nbsp;", " ");

        // Get collection of strings
        MatchCollection matches = regx.Matches(str);

        // Add to the hash set
        HashSet<string> hashSet = new HashSet<string>();
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            hashSet.Add(match.Value);
        }

        // Return set of url
        return hashSet;
    }
```

How can I call it without creating other methods? I tried this way:

```
HashSet<string> hashSet = new HashSet<string>();
hashSet = Client.getLinks("http://www." + textBox1.Text);
```

But got an error: `Can not convert Task<HashSet<string>> to HashSet<string>.` Then I tried:

```
hashSet = Client.getLinks("http://www." + textBox1.Text).Result;
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Your methods return type is `Task<HashSet<string>>` but your code is returning `HashSet<string>`

Comment: @stackErr That's correct, it's an `async` method.

Comment: @Servy :O! I didn't know this was possible....time to MSDN! :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `await` keyword:

```
hashSet = await Client.getLinks("http://www." + textBox1.Text);
```